# Ant design form

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I get an error that can't setvalue when I execute the onBlur function. But when I remove name attribute in Form.Item it works again.
why when having name attribute it doesn't work.

```
const App = () => {
  const [valuess, setValue] = useState("");
  const onBlur = () => {
    let str = valuess;
    str = str
      .normalize("NFD")
      .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
      .replace(/[đĐ]/g, (m) => (m === "đ" ? "d" : "D"))
      .toUpperCase();
    setValue(str);
    console.log(str);
  };
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="fullname"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your username!"
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Input
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          value={valuess}
          onBlur={onBlur}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: I created a sandbox for your code and seems working fine https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-violet-80vri4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When you add `name` attribute and your form is wrapped with `Form` component then it is controlled by form itself. Use form hook to set values like this:
form.setFieldsValue({ fullname: <VALUE>  })